# How does the client side know when the server waits for data in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

This is my client code:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Socket socket  = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        socket = new Socket(args[0], serverPort);    
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true){
            String temp=in.readLine();
            if (temp==null){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }catch (UnknownHostException e)  {System.out.println("Socket:"+e.getMessage());}    
     catch (EOFException e){System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage());}
     catch (IOException e){System.out.println("readline:"+e.getMessage());}
     finally {if(socket!=null) try {socket.close();}catch (IOException e){System.out.println("close:"+e.getMessage());}}
 }
```

This is a part of my server code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try{
        int serverPort = 7896; // the server port
        ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Request from client" + clientSocket.getInetAddress()+"at port "+ clientSocket.getPort());               
            Connection c = new Connection(clientSocket);
        }
     } catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("Listen socket:"+e.getMessage());}
}

private static class Connection extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;

    public Connection(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println("New client connected at " + socket);
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
           try {
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
               PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
               begin(in,out);  
           }catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error handling client");
           }finally{
                 try { socket.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
                 System.out.println("Connection with client closed");
           }
    }

}

public static void begin(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out){
    String userChoice=null;

    out.println("----------");
    out.println("MailServer:");
    out.println("----------");
    out.println("Hello, you connected as a guest.");
    printMenu(out); //a menu with some choices

    out.println("Please type your choice: ");
    try{
        userChoice=in.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In the client side I show all messages from the server inside that while loop. The thing is after some messages the server waits for a message from the client. And after that, server sends more messages and again waits for a message from the client. How do I know that sometimes the server stops sending messages and waits for an answer? I'm going to use the out variable from the client for that. Will I do that inside that while loop?

Comment: You need to devise a **protocol**. That is how a client and server communicate. Without one, you'd just be flailing in the dark.

Comment: Are asking specifically, how the client knows that the server is waiting? If so, @ElliottFrisch suggestion is correct. I can help you with a solution if you give some more clarity

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to create a mailserver. That menu gives the client some options(Login,register etc). After the client sends his message(login,register etc) other messages will be sent to the client from the server(a menu with Send an email, read emails etc) and again the server will wait for a message(a choice from the new menu for example read emails) and so on..

Comment: @SavvasTh Is the answer I posted helpful or not, please respect that it takes a lot more time to help very vague and malformed questions like yours.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, I checked your answer but I solved it with another similar way. Every time the server needed a reply I sent a message before like "waiting_for_reply" and inside the client app I was checking for every message if the message equals to that it means the server waits for a reply. Not the best way to solve it but anw! Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

As someone suggested in the comments, you must define a protocol for your specific client-server interaction, that means the client must know what all the possible responses from the server will be and to handle those in a unified way you decide and the same for all possible calls from a client to a server. You should checkout [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introducing-threads-socket-programming-java/) for further inspiration.

I cannot help you define a protocol as that is up to you and your business logic and beyond the scope of this platform but I can say that you need to make a few tweaks to be able to listen for messages from clients on the server.

Client code tweak:

```
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    Socket socket  = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        socket = new Socket(args[0], serverPort);    
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true){
            String temp=in.readLine();
            if (temp==null){
                break;
            }

            String x = "empty" // name this some default option so you can handle it in the server and know that it was never set
            if (temp == "Hello, you connected as a guest.") {
                // process the help menu items here and make a decision on what to send
                // ex) you chose option 'A', save it in a variable, lets say String x = "A"
            } else if (temp == ) {
                // now that the server asks for your response, you know that it is waiting... send the response
                // out.println(x) 
            }
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }catch (UnknownHostException e)  {System.out.println("Socket:"+e.getMessage());}    
     catch (EOFException e){System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage());}
     catch (IOException e){System.out.println("readline:"+e.getMessage());}
     finally {if(socket!=null) try {socket.close();}catch (IOException e){System.out.println("close:"+e.getMessage());}}
}
```

Server code tweak:

```
private static class Connection extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public Connection(Socket socket, BufferedReader input, PrintWriter output) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.in = in
        this.out = output
        System.out.println("New client connected at " + socket);
        this.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            begin()
        }
    }

    public static void begin(){
        String userChoice = null;

        out.println("----------");
        out.println("MailServer:");
        out.println("----------");
        out.println("Hello, you connected as a guest.");
        printMenu(out); //a menu with some choices

        this.out.println("Please type your choice: ");
        try{
            userChoice = this.in.readLine();
            // handle user choices here
                if (userChoice == "A") {
                // do whatever you need for option A
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try{
        int serverPort = 7896; // the server port
        ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Request from client" + clientSocket.getInetAddress()+"at port "+ clientSocket.getPort());

            try {
                BufferedReader socketInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter socketOutput = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);               
                Connection c = new Connection(clientSocket, socketInput, socketOutput);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error handling client");
            } finally{
                try { socket.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
                System.out.println("Connection with client closed");
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Listen socket:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```